# Browser auto-complete problem

Tags: c#

I have a problem.

I have TextBox1 where I enter information:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
as
sd
asdasd
asdas
d
```

These data are stored in the browser.
I do not want successors to the data re-appear in the browser.
How can it be reached?

Comment: duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893799/can-i-disallow-web-browser-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set **autocomplete="off"** MasterPage form tag