# Disable Textbox suggestions

Tags: html, textbox

Hi all you all have experienced that when you use a`textbox` again and again by writing something in it and submitting the values the textbox starts to give you suggestion on the `onfocus` event based on previous written values. Can we disable this attribute of the textbox that it shouldn't suggest previous values?

Comment: Possible duplicate, please see this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/...disallow-web-browser-autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893799/can-i-disallow-web-browser-autocomplete) for a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

autocomplete="off" add this as attribute to your control
e.g.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Even it's implemented on a single textbox; It disables all the textboxes in the form, not able to type in any of my text boxes.

Comment: Autocomplete attribute is toggling autocomplete inside text box. This attribute is not responsible for the status of the text box. So, if autocomplete is off or on your text box will be enabled. Check if your form is disabled.

Comment: Yes, it was the attribute in form tag. Thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

You can try this code

`<input autocomplete="nope" name="clent_email" id="clent_email" type="text"`>

change **autocomplete="off"** to **autocomplete="nope**"

Comment: wtf this actually worked.. it still didn't with form but it did with imput

Comment: edit: not a long-term solution.. ended up using js instead..

Comment: The reason this worked is that some browsers (especially Chrome) intentionally ignore `autocomplete="off"`, as they've decided that behavior is more what users want. However `"nope"` isn't defined as one of the possible values for `autocomplete`, and the spec requires that they not make assumptions about what an undefined value means. In this case, they interpret it to do no autocomplete, which is what you're looking for.