# When you type something in a text box and press submit it appears in a list below the text box permerantly

Tags: html

I've tried multiple options already and nothing works.
When you type something in a text box and press submit it appears in a list below the text box permanently so it appears in a paragraph below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Textbox suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205518/disable-textbox-suggestions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I disallow web browser autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893799/can-i-disallow-web-browser-autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

You can find an answer here: [Disable Textbox suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205518/disable-textbox-suggestions)

But to sum that up, add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to whatever text box is causing the problem.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

**Note:** The `autocomplete` attribute works with the following `<input>` types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.