# How to stop text suggestions from textbox

Tags: html, css, input, textbox

Is there a way to stop the text suggestions that display when you click on a text box, i.e a drop down which shows the previous text you have entered in that field earlier? I don't know what it is called, so not having any luck Googling. I am using a calendar control but the text suggestions are hiding part of it (screenshot below). Want to get rid of the drop down dates.

[image]

Comment: This may be your possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205518/disable-textbox-suggestions

Comment: Perfect, what I was looking for, Thank you!