# how to avoid listing previously entered values in certain text fields of a form? HTML, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

In my HTML FORMs, when I focus certain text fields they list down history of values entered previously. Is it possible to avoid this auto-drop-down? I am not looking for some browser settings tips for my computer, instead, I want these settings for all of the users of my website filling a form.

Will it also be possible to apply these settings for some selected text fields only? as historical values for some text fields may be helpful for a particular user using his/her machine.

May be this could be achieved using Javascript, but no clue where to start from.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I am using PHP and Javascript (JQuery).

Comment: Name the field something crazy that they probably have never encountered before. :)

Comment: @Tim .. LOL .. but the solution I am looking for is for users using my website's forms again and again.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Please disregard my comment then. :)

Comment: Note that if you have autocomplete="off" on a password field, Firefox will not save the password. However, if the password is already saved, it will be populated in a password field, even if autocomplete="off".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to each of your form elements.

This is not part of the W3C HTML standard, but it does work in both Mozilla & IE browsers.

Comment: I think this is an Internet Explorer specific thing.

Comment: In which standard is this defined? In which browser is this implemented?

Comment: It is not defined in any standard, but I haven't seen a browser that does autocomplete that does *not* obey this tag.

Comment: will it pass thru validation tests?

Comment: accessibility validation, and html validation

Comment: Invented by Microsoft, but now in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) and supported by all major browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML_5)

Comment: This answer doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox on password fields, the browser ignores it

Answer (score 3):

Try autocomplete="off" in your `<form>` or `<input>` tag, see [this Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_form_Autocompletion), [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx) and [this Safari Reference page](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058#//apple_ref/html/attribute/autocomplete) for more info. Looks like Safari has only documented the use of the attribute on individual `<input>` tags though.

See also the answers to the question [How can I prevent Firefox’s Autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682439/how-can-i-prevent-firefoxs-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is implemented in firefox using an internal table with field names and their history. You can try to generate a custom name for your fields (like "name-asdfg" instead of just "name"), which results in a form generation and processing overhead (you must strip the nonsense from the end of the name).