# Firefox autofilling username/password

Tags: firefox, authentication, autocomplete

One of my user complained that whenever he tried to add a new user (auth.User) using the default admin interface (Django's admin), the new username and password would get automatically filled with his own.

The problem is he asked Firefox to remember his username/password when he logs in. Is there any way I can prevent Firefox from trying to autofill when not on the login page? I don't really understand what critera Firefox looks at when trying to autofill. The URL is obviously not the same; does it rely only on the domain name and the names (or IDs) of the html fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682439/how-can-i-prevent-firefoxs-autocomplete/682459), it appears as though you can add an attribute to your form

```
autocomplete="off"
```

This should prevent FireFox from autofilling the form in the admin.  I'm pretty new to Django, but I imagine that you would need to copy & customize the specific template in the admin where you want this behavior in order to add this attribute.